# How can I open a JavaFX GUI from JavaSwing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

I created a swing GUI, and a graph using JavaFX. I would like to open the graph by clicking a button on the swing GUI. My Code is below. Thank you for your help.

This is what I have to open the FX GUI from the swing GUI.

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Test Graph = new Test();
        Graph.GrpahScreen();
    }       
});
```

> FX class

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // TODO
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Application` class represents a JavaFX Application. Since you are writing a Swing application (with JavaFX content embedded in it), it makes no sense to create an `Application` subclass.

Additionally, it is highly recommended **not** to use both JavaFX `Stage`s and Swing `JFrame`s in the same application. You should place the JavaFX content in a `JFXPanel` and display the `JFXPanel` in a `JFrame`. You need to be careful to obey the threading restrictions of *both* toolkits: as usual, Swing components **must** be created on the AWT event dispatch thread, and JavaFX components **must** be created on the JavaFX application Thread. This is all covered in detail in the [`JFXPanel` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), but in essence:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Parent root = ... ; // create JavaFX content, can be in a separate class
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        });
        frame.add(jfxPanel);
        frame.setSize(...);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }       
});
```